# rename columns with a loop

Tags: r, loops, rename

Afternoon.  I have a dataset with multiple scales in them.  I'm renaming the columns with the scale name and item number (ex_1, ex_2... etc.)  Is there a more efficient way to do this if you know the column positions in the df?

This is how I've been renaming.

`df_R <- df %>%  rename(ECR_1 = 6, ECR_2 = 7, ECR_3 = 8, ECR_4 = 9, ECR_5 = 10, ECR_6 = 11,  ECR_7 = 12, ECR_8 = 13, ECR_9 = 14, ECR_10 = 15, ECR_11 = 16, ECR_12 = 17,  ECR_13 = 18, ECR_14 = 19, ECR_15 = 20)`

Comment: How about this? `names(df)[6:20] <- paste0("ECR_",seq(1:15))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within the `tidyverse` using `rename_with`, keeping the first 5 names without any trailing names

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename_with(function(x) c(x[1:5], paste0("ECR_", seq(15))))
```